# Changing other columns value onselectedvaluechanged event in combobox in XtraGridView

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtragrid

Is there a way to get handle of row of which the selectionvalue is changed in combobox?

Let me try to explain it using example.
In GridView, I have two columns,
Name, Type

Type column has combobox, with values 1 and 2.

What I want to do is on selecting value 1 in type column ,
I want to change the Name to "One"

On selecting 2 in type column,
I want to change the Name to "Two"

This is what I was trying,

```
 private void OnType_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit comboType = sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit;
    DataRow row = (DataRow) myGridView.GetFocusedRow();            
    if (comboType .SelectedItem.ToString() == "1") 
            {
                 row.Name = "one";
            }else
            {
             row.Name = "two";
             }
   }
```

But here I am getting myGridView.GetFocusedRow() as null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is to bind a repository editor to column.

```
RepositoryItemComboBox riCmb = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
```

Handle the **editvaluechanged** event

```
riCmb.EditValueChanged += riCmb_EditValueChanged;
```

Then inside the event handler

```
if(myGridView.GetRowCellValue(myGridView.FocusedRowHandle, "FieldName").ToString() == "1")
{
      grvInstruments.SetRowCellValue(grvInstruments.FocusedRowHandle, "FieldName", "One");
}
```

Comment: You may use SetFocusedRowCellValue(col, value) if you don't want to provide the row handle